# Button, if statements and bool causing issues - can't get my head around it :(

Tags: c#, if-statement, button, boolean

Had an issue that I've been trying to work out for the best part of 2 hours now - and im guessing its something simple...

working on a tic tac toe game & got the majority of it working, adding "X" into the boxes on button click ect.
However, when I check to see if there are 3 in a row, it doesn't seem to be registering.

```
                bool winner = false;


            if ((button1.Text == button2.Text) && (button2.Text == button3.Text) && (button1.Equals("X")))
            {
                winner = true;
                if (winner)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Awesome");
                }
```

This does not seem to work at all. However, if I make just 1 change (adding ! before button1.Equals("X")))) as shown below

```
                bool winner = false;


            if ((button1.Text == button2.Text) && (button2.Text == button3.Text) && (!button1.Equals("X")))
            {
                winner = true;
                if (winner)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Awesome");
                }
```

It works perfectly (in terms of giving me the MessageBox.Show ("Awesome");, which happens before I can play the game as, all the button.text' are blank.

Just incase it makes a difference, I have assigned each button clicked a value in another method (Button_Click, object sender ect...)

```
 public void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button clickedBtn = (Button)sender;
    if (Turn)
    {
        clickedBtn.Text = "X";
    }
    else
    {
        clickedBtn.Text = "O";
    }
    Turn = !Turn;
    clickedBtn.Enabled = false;
}
```

also - all buttons created are dynamic. as shown below:

```
Button button1 = new Button();
        button1.Left = 0;
        button1.Top = 0;
        button1.Width = 100;
        button1.Height = 100;
        button1.Click += new EventHandler(Button_Click);
```

button2 & 3 are applied the same way.
When testing, I found that this, when also applied to buttons 1,2 & 3:

```
Button button1 = new Button();
        button1.Left = 0;
        button1.Top = 0;
        button1.Width = 100;
        button1.Height = 100;
        button1.Text = "X";
        button1.Click += new EventHandler(Button_Click);
```

caused the event to run fine! (notice the button1.Text = "X";

Any ideas what could be the problem?

Thanks!

@InBetween I have now editted the post and added more of the code you required.

Answer (score 0):

`Button1.Equals("X")` is always false. A button is never a string "X". You want be doing `Button1.Text.Equals("X")`

Comment: Hi bud, I've just tried that, and it still doesnt seem to be working! I've also tried using clickedBtn.Enabled = false; and using it being disabled as a condition

 if ((button1.Text == button2.Text) && (button2.Text == button3.Text) && (!button1.Enabled))

But still nothing is working =/

Comment: Try Button1.Text == "X"

Comment: Well then, the text on buttons 1, 2 and 3 is not "X". You are either looking at the wrong buttons or you are setting their `Text` property to something else; lower case `x` maybe?

Comment: Ah ok, so taking what you said I decided to test by manually applying button5,6,7.Text = "x".. which seemed to work.
So I guess the problem is within the code:

clickedBtn.Text = "x";

It seems it is not making button1.Text = "x" which is strange.

Can anyone advise an alternative way?

Comment: @v3ng3anc3 well, show us the code where you are dinamically creating the buttons and adding the event handler (and the event handler itself).  Can't tell you much with the code you've posted so far.

Comment: @JuniorJohn `string == string` and `string.Equals(string)` are equivalent. I'm not really sure what you expected would behave differently.